# Use ffmpeg to concatenate a video and a timelapse

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, frame, frame-rate

Input 1: I used my phone to record a 25 fps movie with 1920x1080 resolution. There is sound.

Input 2: I used ffmpeg to create a timelapse movie i.e. 25 fps made out of 1920x1080 JPEGs. There is no sound.

When I tried to concatenate them however, the result was a mess: It seems some fine detail is not matching between the two inputs, because the resulting video squishes the time lapse down to just 1 frame at the end.

I have also tried this by first removing sound from video 1, so that both videos are soundless, and this does not give a different result.

How can I tell ffmpeg that the two inputs are not incongruent, so as to achieve a correct 25 fps 1920x1080 video using all the frames from both inputs?.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What you need in output? (fps and resolution is not enough). Speed up video and concat with images slideshow?